# NAnt Property to lowercase

Tags: string, nant

I want to protect against incorrect case being placed within a parameter in a nant script.

I want to take the value of x and convert it to lower case, I tried using

```
string::to-lower()
```

but that did not work hoping someone has come across this and has a simple solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <project name="test" Default="test" value="net-4.0" >

     <property name="x" value="default" unless="${property::exists('x')}"/>

     <target name="test">
       <echo message="${x}" />
     </target>
   </project>
```

**UPDATE**

I tried the suggestion put forward by Yan with the code below this still outputs capitals I will explain further

I have a nant script that has a parameter that can be passed into it, a property checks for the existence of the parameter and if it exists it uses it, if not there is a default value. I want to take the parameter in whatever form it is given and convert it to lower case while still checking for its existence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<property overwrite="true" name="x" value="default" unless="${property::exists('x')}"/>
<property overwrite="true" name="x" value="${string::to-lower(x)}" />

<target name="test">
    <echo message="${x}" />
</target>
</project>
```

I believe this to be the way you think I should do it Yan. I have tested this with the following command line arguments.

```
nant -buildfile:nant.build test -D:x=TEST
```

This produces the output

```
 Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0
 Target(s) specified: test

 [property] Read-only property "x" cannot be overwritten.

 test:

 [echo] TEST

 BUILD SUCCEEDED - 0 non-fatal error(s), 1 warning(s)

 Total time: 0.1 seconds.
```

any solution would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say parameter, so you mean its name or its value? ie, do you want to ensure `x` is lowercase, or `test` (I assume the latter)? If I have the following nant script:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="test" Default="test" value="net-4.0" >

    <property overwrite="false" name="x" value="default"/>
    <property overwrite="false" name="x_internal" value="${string::to-lower(x)}" />

    <target name="test">
        <echo message="${x_internal}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

And call it like this:

```
nant.exe -buildfile:nant.build test -D:x=TESTx
nant.exe -buildfile:nant.build test -D:X=TESTX
```

I receive the following response:

```
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0
Target(s) specified: test

test:

     [echo] testx

BUILD SUCCEEDED
Total time: 0 seconds.

Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0
Target(s) specified: test

test:

     [echo] default

BUILD SUCCEEDED
Total time: 0 seconds.
```

Is this what you are after?

**UPDATE**

I think this is what is tripping you up:

```
Note: properties set on the command-line are always read-only.
```

(From [section 4 in the NAnt Properties documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/fundamentals/properties.html))

Answer (score 0):

The function you mentioned should work. See if you spelled the syntax correctly:

```
<echo message="${string::to-lower(x)}" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, string::to-lower does work on its own thanks. The problem I may not have explained well enough, is given that parameter x exists convert it to lower case. The code above is a representation of the problem in its simplest form.

Comment: Well, don't understand what doesn't work then. If you want `x` to contain the lower-cased version of itself, you can do something like this: `<property name="x" value="${string::to-lower(x)}" />`